# How to find heading with specific tag in a directory? (not in org-agenda-files)

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a list of **.org** files in a directory.

I want to search in all of those **.org** files using `org-tags-view`.
But `org-tags-view` only searches in the files that defined by `org-agenda-files`.

How do I use `org-tags-view` with the files in the current directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can let bind `org-agenda-files`, eg.

```
(defun my-tags-view (&optional directory)
  "With prefix arg, prompt for DIRECTORY to search tags."
  (interactive (list (if current-prefix-arg (read-directory-name "Directory: "))))
  (let ((org-agenda-files (if directory (list directory)
                            org-agenda-files)))
    ;; forward prefix arg - this makes it so prefix args passed to `org-tags-view'
    ;; require one more prefix, eg. C-u C-u my-tags-view => todo-only tags
    (setq current-prefix-arg
          (unless (equal current-prefix-arg '(4))
            (list (ash (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg) -2))))
    (call-interactively #'org-tags-view)))
```

Answer (score 0):

After 25 min searching to find a way, I decided to use this.

1. use [deft-mode](https://github.com/jrblevin/deft)

   - search for *:blog:*
2. use **grep**

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.org" -exec grep -i -n ":blog:" {} +
```

Comment: As long as you realize that you can get false matches (i.e. instances of `:blog:` that are not tags), that's a perfectly fine solution. The colons make it unlikely that such false matches will occur, but it is not impossible. `let-binding` the variable `org-agenda-files` as in the other answer, *does* take care of that. Moreover, it's a technique that has wide applicability in Emacs, so it's worth remembering.