# Emacs org-mode: Find Tags in Folder

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am learning to use Emacs and Org Mode.

I was initially getting no results when I clicked on a tag. I solved my own problem by doing `C-c [` (`Ctrl-c` then `[`) which adds the file to the 'agenda' with the [org-agenda-file-to-front command](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Files.html#index-C_002dc-_005b)... But is this the right way to do this, you have to manually add all files you want searched to the 'agenda'?

[According to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384516/how-to-make-all-org-files-under-a-folder-added-in-agenda-list-automatically) you can run a lisp command to add all the .org files in a folder but it doesn't add any files added after the command is ran. It should not be this difficult to get a list of tags in this and other files... am I heading in the wrong direction?

Simple example:

```
* Things to do
** Eat                                                          :plate:chair:
*** Spaghetti
** Code                                                      :computer:chair:
** Sleep
```

[image]

> I can click on the :chair: tag on the right, and I expect that I would
> have a list of headlines that use that clicked tag in another buffer,
> but nothing was returned for "Headlines with TAGS match: chair" unless
> the file is added to the 'agenda'.

I found [a question that seems to have the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966333/emacs-org-mode-tags-not-found) but you still have to run it each time you add a file. Can someone provide a simplified explanation for what technique/setup is needed to just click on a tag and have all the org files in a folder be searched for that tag?

Comment: To limit the tags to just files in the directory, the trick is to let bind `org-agenda-files` to contain the directory, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76450228/how-to-find-heading-with-specific-tag-in-a-directory-not-in-org-agenda-files/76452732#76452732